'onTap' isn't working, After fixing the "setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build." error
I am building the BMI calculator app,
after all, it giving me "setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build." error.
so, i come up with below solution..
onTap: () {
                        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){
                          // This is cause of "setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build." error.
                          setState(() {
                            selectedGender = Gender.male;
                          });
                        });
                      },

the error is gone,
but buttons are not working..
(like selecting male, female etc.)
full code:
    children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded( // for Male // child,colour,cardChild are the parameters for the constructor
                    child: ReusableCard(
                      onPress: () {
                        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){
                          // This is cause of "setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build." error.
                          setState(() {
                            selectedGender = Gender.male;
                          });
                        });
                      },
                      colour: selectedGender == Gender.male ? kActiveCardColour : kInactiveCardColour, // from constants.dart
                      cardChild: IconContent(
                        icon: FontAwesomeIcons.mars,
                        label: 'MALE',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded( // for Female
                    child: ReusableCard(
                      onPress: () {
                        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){
                          // This is cause of "setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build." error.
                          setState(() {
                            selectedGender = Gender.female;
                          });
                        });
                      },
                      colour: selectedGender == Gender.female ? kActiveCardColour : kInactiveCardColour,
                      cardChild: IconContent(
                        icon: FontAwesomeIcons.venus,
                        label: 'FEMALE',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// card for male, female etc..

class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {

  final Color colour;
  final Widget cardChild;
  final Function onPress;

  // Constructor
  ReusableCard({required this.colour, required this.cardChild, required this.onPress});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onPress(),
      child: Container(
        child: cardChild,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        // color: colour, can't use cause..  color is short-hand of from BoxDecoration
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: colour,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

code is about select make or female,
the container will change properties according to onPress()
but after the running the code,
i presses the that containers, doesn't happen anything..

Using directly onTap: onPress() will call the method during build time. You can create an anonymous function/ which will trigger onPressed,
 onTap:()=> onPress(),

Or You can just use VoidCallback instead of Function.
 final VoidCallback onPress;

And use like onTap: onPress. No need to use postFrameCallback.

and the form onTap: onPress should be the preferred way... i mean it should be noted first

yap, while asking solving bugs/answering I kinda goes what's wrong with current one -> how can I solve it -> are there any better approach. Ig that's why I ended writing like this.  btw found you after a long time @pskink

i was always here ;-)

humz, maybe I was kinda busy with project. nowadays cant find enough fun on SO, less question than before.

In my case  "onTap:()=> onPress()", is not working, but  "final VoidCallback onPress;"
is working..
